# Numerical recipe for interpolating a gradient in n dimensions

Tags: numerical-methods, vector-analysis

I have a large set of points in $n$-dimensional space and each point has a scalar associated with it. I would like to compute the gradient of the associated function.

If the points I'm considering were two-dimensional, I would do the following :

- generate Delaunay triangulation from the set of points
- assume the function is linear on each mesh element
- interpolate the gradient on each mesh element

If the points spaced out on a regular grid in $n$-dimensions, I would simply separate the dimensions, and compute the gradient in each direction.

But I don't know how to extend this to the $n$-dimensional case with points that are unevenly spread out. How can I interpolate a gradient on an irregular grid in $n$-dimensions?

Comment: You still can construct Delaunay triangulation in n dimensions. In fact, your problem is not about the gradient, but instead about how to interpolate function in n dimensions, you may check [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation#Irregular_grid_(scattered_data)). For the gradient you simply take the derivatives of the interpolant.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40520133/12283493) is an interesting method.